# Convert MySQL Variable Query to PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql, variables

I have migrated MYSQL database to PostgreSQL and I am now converting my queries to match. I have this MySQL query in the Python file:

```
SET @Drop_Stm = CONCAT('DROP TABLE ', (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(TABLE_NAME) AS All_Tables 
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'temp_%' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = '{client_name}'))
```

I would like to make it works in Postgres, I tried the following but returns error:

```
WITH Drop_Stm AS (CONCAT('DROP TABLE ', (SELECT STRING_AGG(TABLE_NAME, ',') AS All_Tables 
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'temp_%' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = '{client_name}')))

LINE 1: WITH Drop_Stm AS (CONCAT('DROP TABLE ', (SELECT STRING_AGG(T...
                      ^
```

I also tried DECLARE, SET, and DO $$ .. END $$ with no luck

Comment: What are you planning to do with that "variable" if it was possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query itself should be changed to this:

```
select concat('drop table ', string_agg(format('%I.%I', table_schema, table_name), ','), ' cascade;')
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'temp_%' 
  AND TABLE_SCHEMA = '{client_name}'
```

Note that I used the `format()` function to properly deal with identifiers needing quoting. I also generated a fully qualified table name (including the schema) so that you don't accidentally drop a table in the current schema, rather than `{client_name}`.

If you want to run the generated script, I see two options. One is to put this into a PL/pgSQL block and use execute:

```
do
$$
declare
  l_stmt text;
begin
  select concat('drop table ', string_agg(format('%I.%I', table_schema, table_name), ','), ' cascade;')
    into l_stmt
  FROM information_schema.tables 
  WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'temp_%' 
    AND TABLE_SCHEMA = '{client_name}';
  
  execute l_stmt;
end;
$$
;
```

I don't know Python, so I am not entirely sure if `{client_name}` gets replaced correctly with that approach.

Another option is to run the SELECT query in Python, and store the result into a Python variable then run that SQL through Python.

Comment: Hi @a_horse_with_no_name, thank you for answering this question. I want the `SET @Drop_Stm` variable that works in MySQL to be converted to Postgres along with this whole bunch of code. Mind telling me how to do that?

Comment: Again: what do you want to do with that (SQL) variable (if it did exist, which it does not). The closest you can get is the PL/pgSQL block where I store that into a variable.

Comment: Hi @a_horse_with_no_name, I have this error `syntax error at or near "execute"`

Comment: @iBoon: ah, sorry. there was a `;` missing at the end of the SELECT

Comment: Sorry @a_horse_with_no_name, another one `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "into"`

Comment: @iBoon: works for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=c9d3ac8f45682d7c21ddd82fed54d80b maybe your SQL client can't cope with the "dollar quoted" DO block